# Relationship of Planck units and duration of a rebirth in Naraka

Tags: hells, metaphysics

My intuition is telling me that since the last level of hell is some kind of a mathematical limit of how stupid a person can get (or how annoying or how evil), there must be a parallel with Planck units, which are the minimum measurable amounts of physical quantities.  (or equivalently, maximum, when considered how many you can fit in something else)  The Planck time, in this context, to be precise.

What is the statistically average duration of a birth in Naraka, the non-stop hell? We could consider that a sort of Planck-lifetime of a being, especially since to the outside observer, a hell lasting billions of years might look much shorter than for the being in hell. Therefore, the Planck-lifetime of a hell being during a single rebirth might actually be comparably short as the physical Planck-time when observed from the outside.

Comment: Often a "good answer" is based "Something that happened to you **personally**" and/or "Something you can **back up** with a reference" -- https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ -- do you think this is that kind of question? "What is the statistically average duration of a birth in Naraka ..."

Comment: so it’s not good to ask a question on evolving our understanding of the relationship between physics and the Dhamma? you’re probably right technically, but I feel it’s worth the tradeoff risk. You know it’s not good karma to be 100% stuck to rules.

Comment: besides, the duration of a hell rebirth can be answered factually, even if it is not a single scalar value. and the relationship between that and the duration of being in hell can also be computed. so what is the problem?

Comment: Suffering and stress.

Comment: what is the difference between suffering and stress?

Comment: Good question, why not ask it? Personally, I think the answer may be seen in "The Arrow" https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN36_6.html

Comment: As far as I see, ‘suffering’ and ‘stress’ are synonyms.  That sutta talks about how various types of persons react to factors of suffering/stress. In fact, the sutta directly confirms my statement: _“/…/ He is joined, I tell you, with suffering & stress.”_ — suffering and stress are semantically equated — the distinction is laid upon different reactions to s-&-s, _not_ the difference between s-vs-s.

Answer (score 0):

What you perceive to be some idea of life after death, is actually the mind's method of holding itself captive within the world of form. Whether you think it's just for fun or not, the mind uses imaginary ideas about a series of sequential events in order to perpetuate this illusion. In short, freedom is right here, right now. The quagmire is that when you look at just what is, in this moment, there is a haze over the perception which appears to create a blockade. The mind then turns inwards, towards its imaginary world and entertains its various delusions, including that of hell realms.